# how to save images in to particular path when image is give from link or url, in python

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save images that are given from link, such a way that, image save in the given path and image file_name is created with `uuid` like below:

my profile model is:

```
class Profile(DataTimeModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null=True, blank=True)
    citizenship_no = models.CharField(max_length = 25, null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now when the profile is enrolled I will send multiple image link or single, from these link I need to download the image and save to the file path like below:

```
root_dir = MEDIA_ROOT+'/profile/'
new_dir = str(profile.id)
file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())+'.jpeg'
path = os.path.join(root_dir, new_dir)
os.makedirs(path)
```

Now, I need to save the image that comes from the URL into the `path` folder with image name `file_name` with extension. How can I do that?
I try by using
`urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)`

this but it saves into base directory but I need to save in given path.

Image link is given from this interface:
[image]

Comment: Why not use `ImageField` or `FileField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the parameter in [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) is called `filename`, you may actually pass in a **file path**:

Simply combine your `path` and `file_name`:

```
path = os.path.join(root_dir, new_dir)
os.makedirs(path)
file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())+'.jpeg'
file_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_path)
```

Comment: no, it makes the folder of file_name, can not save the image inside the folder.

Comment: Um, nope, I tried it myself. Are you calling ``os.makedirs(file_path)``? Because that would be wrong and that's not what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: yes, I did os.makedirs(file_path) this, i will try like you said. thank you

Comment: yes,  this works for single image, when two or more image it save last one, why this appen any idea?

Comment: ok, thank you it works finally. The above issue come because of the same file name.